# remove hyperlink to current page from pagination

Tags: php, javascript, html, pagination

I have dynamic results sets which produce paginated hyperlinks to divide the results into multiple pages. But how can I change this so that the link to the current page is un-hyperlinked, and maybe also a different color or font weight? Thanks.

```
if($rs_result->num_rows >10){
   $page_range_offset = 4;
   $page_start = $page - $page_range_offset;
if ($page_start < 1) {
    $page_start = 1;
   }

    $page_end = $page + $page_range_offset;
if ($page_end > $total_pages) {
    $page_end = $total_pages;
  }


     $pages = "<p>";
for ($i=$page_start; $i<=$page_end; $i++) {
     $pages .="<a href='inbox.html?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";
  }
     $pages .="</p>";
     echo $pages;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like the following?

```
for ($i=$page_start; $i<=$page_end; $i++)
{

  if ($i == $page)
  {
    $pages .= '<span style="color: #000000">' . $i . '</span>';
  }

  else
  {
     $pages .="<a href='inbox.html?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";
  }

}
```

Comment: that worked a charm. Thanks Micheal, that really helped me out

Comment: I'd say to do something like <span class="selected"> then style it with CSS to follow good practices :)

Comment: `$pages .= '<a class="selected" name="'' . $i . ">' . $i . '</a>';` This would be better, I use name anchor for current page pagination link.. I hope it's helpful to other users